# Google Earth Engine how can I return an image of each iteration

Tags: javascript, iteration, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to map the maximal amount of days without rain using the TRMM dataset in Google Earth Engine. I'm doing this by iterating over the collection and if no rain has fallen, one gets added to the cell (code below). When rain has fallen the value gets multiplied by 0 so the "counter" is reset. Then I would like to store each result of each iteration in a Image collection and then select the maximum value to get the longest consecutive dry period.

But that is the theory. When I put this in a script I get an error while adding the image of one iteration to a list. Does anyone know why this is and how this can be solved?

**Code:**

```
var list = [];
function drylength(current, previous){
  var mask = current.remap([0], [1], 0,"precipitation").rename('precipitation');
  var sum = mask.add(previous).multiply(mask);

  list.push(sum);
  return sum;
}

var dataset = TRMM
.filterDate("2015-01-01","2015-02-01")
.sort('system:time_start:');

var totalPrecipitation = dataset.iterate(drylength, dataset.max()
.remap([0], [0], 0, "precipitation")
.rename('precipitation'));

print(list);
print(totalPrecipitation);
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(totalPrecipitation), imageVisParam);
```

Furthermore it appears only 3 items are stored in the list which makes me assume the iteration is more complex than a literal iteration where all images are calculated one by one? Here is an image of the error:

[image: Google Earth Engine errors]

Errors written if image is not visible or for search engines:

```
Failed to decode JSON.
Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is missing or null.
Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.
```

and:

```
Unknown variable references: [_MAPPING_VAR_0_0, _MAPPING_VAR_0_1].
```

Comment: I have received an answer on a GIS specific stackexchange. If anyone encounters the same problem, go here: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276182/google-earth-engine-how-can-i-return-an-image-for-each-iteration](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276182/google-earth-engine-how-can-i-return-an-image-for-each-iteration)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this to use a multi-value result:

```
function drylength(current, previous) {
  previous = ee.Dictionary(previous)
  var mask = current.remap([0], [1], 0,"precipitation").rename('precipitation');
  var sum = mask.add(previous.get('sum')).multiply(mask);

  var list = previous.get('list')
  list = list.push(sum);
  return ee.Dictionary({sum: sum, list: list})
}
...
var totalPrecipitation = dataset.iterate(drylength, {sum: max, list: ee.List([])})
```

Answer (score 1):

The iterate() function runs on the server, but the list you're attempting to push into is a client-side list; that can't work.  If you make it an ee.List, you might be able to get it to work, but you'll have to put it into the previous result (use previous as a dictionary to hold both).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It indeed makes sense that I should create a list on the server side. I tried turning the list in to an ee.List() but apparently it is not that simple :/ What do you mean with "You'll have to put it into the previous result (use previous as a dictionary to hold both)"? That is something I don't fully understand.